# How to parallelize iteration over a big bytes-type file?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, byte, python-multiprocessing

What i have: bytes file up to 16 GByte with offset (e.g. 100 bytes).
What i need: handle action "f" in code in a fastest way, e.g. i hope with multiprocessing.

I tried to realise http://effbot.org/zone/wide-finder.htm this approach.
A Multi-Threaded Python Solution from that article was two times slower then original code. A Multi-Processor Python Solution i couldn't realise, because my python level is not good enough. I read multiprocessing module description, but it didn't helped for me, i become some problems with code...

```
from time import perf_counter
from random import getrandbits


def create_byte_data(size):
    creation_start = perf_counter()
    my_by = bytes(getrandbits(8) for i in range(size))  # creates 50MB random byte data
    print('creation my_by time = %.1f' % (perf_counter() - creation_start))
    return my_by


def write_to_file(file, data, b):
    writing_start = perf_counter()
    with open(file, "wb") as f:  # binary file creation
        for a in range(offset):
            f.write(b'0')
        # for n in range(b):  # for creating bigger files
        #     f.write(data)
        f.write(data)
    print('writing time = %.1f' % (perf_counter() - writing_start))


def abs_pixel(pixel: bytes) -> int:  # converting signed bytes to absolute (0 +127) values, and collection sum of them to "result"
    result = 0
    for a in pixel:
        if a > 127:
            result += 256 - a
        else:
            result += a
    return result    


def f(file, offset, time):  # this function must be accelerated
    sum_list = list()
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(offset)
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(time)
            if not chunk:
                break
            sum_list.append(abs_pixel(chunk))
    return sum_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'bytes.file'
    offset = 100
    x = 512
    y = 512
    time = 200
    fs = 2  # file size in GBytes  # for creating bigger files
    xyt = x * y * time
    b = fs*1024*1024*1024//xyt  # parameter for writing data file of size 'fs'
    my_data = create_byte_data(xyt)  # don't needed after created ones
    write_to_file(filename, my_data, b)  # don't needed after created ones
    start = perf_counter()
    result = f(filename, offset, time)  # this function must be accelerated
    print('function time = %.1f' % (perf_counter() - start))
    print(result[:10])
```

Task: make some math operations with chunk (that has length "time") and collect results to list. Files can be very big, so RAM must be not overloaded.
Code above can create random bytes file (50 Mb for start, or bigger for further tests). I expect at least 4 time acceleration for running function "f" in comparison to the code above. Actually it needs about 6 seconds on my pc for 50 MByte bytes file and about 240 seconds for 2 GByte file.

Comment: `f` appears to use a global variable `sum_list`. That's going to be a problem if you want to run `f` in multiple threads.

Comment: That said, why doesn't `f` simply build a local list and return it, especially since it appears to clear the list when it first starts?

Comment: Also, it appears every instance of `f` is given a starting point, but reads to the end of the file. Seems like you would want each call to `f` to read a distinct block from the file, so they don't overlap.

Comment: @chepner Thanks! I changed 'sum_list' to not global anymore. 'f' reads only 'time' length. There is no overlap.

Comment: `f.read(time)` reads a chuck of sized `time`, but your *loop* continues to read such chunks until it returns an empty string, which indicates it has reached the end of the file. A call like `f(some_file, 10, t)` will eventually read the same data as `f(some_file, 20, t)`.

Comment: @chepner yes. Offset just says, that image data begins at offset point.

Comment: Then you appear to be doing a lot of redundant work, because `f(file, 0, time)` will read the entire file, `f(file, 100, time)` will read all but the first 100 bytes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to parallelize some part of code mith multiprocessing, and how to make abs_pixel working faster. Now code runs arount 2 times faster (e.g. 6,1s vs 11,9s for 100 MBytes on my PC, or 119s vs 246s for 2 GBytes).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from struct import unpack_from


def abs_pixel_2(pixel: bytes) -> int:  # integral abs
    a = unpack_from('<%ib' % len(pixel), pixel)
    return sum(map(abs, a))


def f_mp(file, offset, time):  # read in lines
    sum_list = list()
    p = Pool()
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(offset)
        for z in range(y*2):  # (y*2) for 100 MByte file (2 times original 50 MBytes created data)
            line = list()
            for i in range(x):  # read a line
                pixel = f.read(time)
                line.append(pixel)
            sums_line = p.map(abs_pixel_2, line)  # line with sums
            # sums_line = list(map(abs_pixel, line))  # line with sums without using of Pool
            sum_list.append(sums_line)  # -> list of lines (lists)
        sum_list = [item for sublist in sum_list for item in sublist]  # flatten of list
        p.close()
        p.join()
    return sum_list
```

But i still hope to find more acceleration points.